# How can I get sans serif linguex glosses?

Tags: fonts, linguistics, sans-serif, linguex, cgloss4e

I am glossing linguistic examples with the linguex package and generally I am very happy with it, so I don't want to use any other enumerating/glossing package. But when I use the Libertine Biolinum (=sans serif) font with it, the glossed examples always appear with serifs. How can I get sans serif glosses?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{linguex}


\begin{document}

\section{Sans serif font: Libertine Biolinum}

Text text text text text

\ex. Linguex numbered example without interlinear glossing
\a. Every layer 
\a. appears in 
\a. sans serif font without interlinear glossing

But as soon as I use interlinear glossing

\exg. Both object language and \\
glossing appear with serifs\\
'Last line is sans serif again.\\




\end{document}
```

[image: Pdf]

Comment: Avoid the trailing ``\\`` in `\exg`, it just causes a warning and does nothing good.

Comment: Just to be clear, only in the last (translation) line, not in the two gloss lines. Better is to use the `\glt` macro to introduce the translation.

Comment: ah I see, thank you. when there is some b example directly following the translation line I usually want some space between these two lines. so its just a habit of mine,  I guess..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell cgloss4e (style file invoked by linguex to handle glosses) that each word in the first and second line of the glossed example is to be set in a sans serif font by adding the following lines to your preamble:

```
\let\eachwordone\sffamily
\let\eachwordtwo\sffamily
```

However, as @egreg notes in the comments below, there's a way of bringing this code more in line with the LaTeX way of doing things by using `\renewcommand`, provided you're running a relatively recent version of cgloss4e:

```
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\textsf}
\renewcommand{\eachwordtwo}{\textsf}
```

Comment: Newer versions of `cgloss4e` can use `\textsf` instead of `\sffamily`; I'd suggest `\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\textsf}` and similarly for `\eachwordtwo`, which is more LaTeX-style.

Comment: Yes, of course, how silly of me. I'll edit my answer directly.

Comment: @egreg Why should we prefer `\textsf` to `\sffamily` here?

Comment: @AlanMunn It's what the package documentation says. But I've no preference. Really, the documentation should have a thorough update.

Comment: @egreg True. :)